# HTML <a> tag wider than specified width

Tags: html, class

http://exfluor.com/productsMain.html

I can't seem to get the boundary of the clickable link area to stay within the bounds of the `<div>` it is making a link(11 buttons linking to product categories).  Even with using a class to specify the width, it spans the entire width of the `<td>` it is in.  I've run out of options.

```
<a href="bycategory.php?cat=anhydrides">
    <div class="category" align="center">
        Anhydrides<br><img src="images/cat/anhydrides.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
</a>
```

Comment: Always post your code in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use block display:

```
.catTable a {
    ...
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To set element's witdth it must have block or inline-block display. Also consider setting overflow: hidden.

Answer (score 0):

Add `word-wrap: break-word` property to your `a`s. It will break your links appropriately. You should pay attention though: You will not get automatic hyphenation from this. For that you would have to look into some library like [hypenator](https://code.google.com/p/hyphenator/)

See this fiddle as an example: http://jsfiddle.net/8Lrhr22u/

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML is not valid. You can't put `div` into `a` (well you can but it's not reliable). Instead try to improve markup a little (`span` instead of `div`):

```
<a href="bycategory.php?cat=hydrofluorocarbons">
    <span class="category" align="center">Hydrofluorocarbons<br>
        <img src="images/cat/hydrofluorocarbons.jpg" alt="">
    </span>
</a>
```

However it's not really necessary, since setting `a` to `display: inline-block` should fix the issue:

```
.catTable a {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: A div inside an anchor is valid in HTML5. Many of us have opted to disregard very old browsers, for better or worse.